# Adding MIME types for Linux Hosting Server (GoDaddy)

Tags: linux, apache, mime-types

Does anyone know how to add recognized filetypes for a non-windows web-hosting server (specifically at GoDaddy). I know on most windows servers you can add a `web.config` file at the root and everything is ready to go. However this does not seem to work on non-windows based servers (Linux).

The reason I need to do this is by default no GoDaddy servers seem to support Theora file formats (ogv, oga, etc). I am working on an HTML5 video player and FireFox works best with Theora format or webm. So I just need to get the server to recognize the file type so I stop getting the grey x (or as I am starting to call it : FGXOD [FireFox Grey 'X' of Death]) where the video should be.

I'm sure there is a simple solution that I am just unaware of at this time.

Comment: You should ask this in http://serverfault.com as it's not really a programming question as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to locate filename: *mime.types*

```
application/x-shockwave-flash swf
```